# Why won't my UIBarButtonItem in my navigation toolbar change titles?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Edit: I forgot to mention that I can't use Apple's predefined edit button because I need the button in the toolbar not the navigation bar (I couldn't figure out a way to add Apple's edit button on the toolbar. If this is possible then please let me know).

I know this question seems like a lot of other questions that have been asked but I have tried the solutions from all of those questions and non of them have helped me solve this problem.

I've researched this problem and tried every solution that I found and could think of.

I've got a UIBarButtonItem which is in my toolbar. It is working as an edit button, so when clicked I want the title to change back to Done. However, whenever I change the title nothing happens. I've tested this value as well and when I print out the value for title I get nil every time. I can't figure this out...

```
@IBOutlet weak var customEditButton: UIBarButtonItem!
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
    customEditButton.title? = "Edit"
    print("customEditButton = \(customEditButton.title)") //This prints nil

    ...
}

@IBAction func editButtonIsClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("MarksTable: editButtonIsClicked")
    if (self.tableView.isEditing) {
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        customEditButton.title? = "Edit"
    }
    else {
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        customEditButton.title? = "Done"
    }
}
```

This not the only thing I've tried. I have also tried

`customEditButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Done", ...)`
but this also failed.

Does anyone know why this is happening or have a solution to the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure you can change the title after initializing the bar button. Have you tried creating an editBarButtonItem and doneBarButtonItem programmatically with titles and corresponding actions. Then toggle between them in code, that is adding and removing the other from the toolbar.

Comment: @AlanPerez no I haven't tried that. I'll give it a shot and see if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to reproduce your issue on my own project and I have it running correctly.

It is possible that your issue lies in the *System Item* type of the button you have added to the Toolbar. Go to storyboards, select your button, and make sure you set its *System Item* to **Custom** in the Attributes Inspector, instead of Edit. Initially, I tried using Edit but its just not as simple to change the title as if you have it set as Custom.

After this I created an outlet and an action from the button, just as you did in your code.

1. Here's the outlet -> 
   `@IBOutlet weak var editBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!`
2. And here's the button action:

   ```
   @IBAction func tappedEditButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

     if tableView.editing {
         tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
         editBarButton.title = "Edit"
     } else {
         tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
         editBarButton.title = "Done"
     }
   ```

Hopefully this works well to solve your problem, best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! The problem was that I had the button set to Edit and not Custom.